# Template only contains the last element of an array passed by context

Tags: arrays, django, templates

I'm on Django 2.2 and I'm try to parse through an array in my HTML template. But for some reason, only the last element of the array is displayed.

Here's mydata, we can that *status* is an array of str:

```
QueryDict: {'managername': ['blabla'], 'plant': ['FR'], 'status': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

This is stored in a variable that I pass through the context:

```py
context = {
     'data': mydata
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, whatever))
```

In the HTML template, I do this :

```html
<label> {{ data.status }} </label>
```

When I get to the HTML, here's what displayed

> c

Is there some trick I'm missing to have the whole array and not just the last element ?

Comment: This is the behavior of subscripting a querydict: "*Returns the value for the given key. If the key has more than one value, it returns the last value.*": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the `QueryDict` is [implemented for subscripting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__):

> **`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`**
>
> Returns the value for the given key. **If the key has more than one
>   value, it returns the last value**. Raises
>   `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError` if the key does
>   not exist. (This is a subclass of Python’s standard `KeyError`, so you
>   can stick to catching `KeyError`.)

You can call the [**`.getlist()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) in the view:

```
context = {
    'data': mydata,
    'statuses': mydata.getlist('status')
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, whatever))
```

and in the template use:

```
<label> {{ statuses }} </label>
```

Comment: That was it. Guess I'll have to spend more time reading the doc next time. thanks!